# How to visualize/connect vectors, matrices and representations in Python and numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am having trouble visualizing scalars, vectors and matrices as how they are written in a math/physics class to how they would be represented in plain Python and `numpy` and their corresponding notions of dimensions, axes and shapes.

1. If I have a scalar, say `5`

```
>>> b = np.array(5)
>>> np.ndim(b)
0
```

I have 0 dimensions for `5` but what are the `axes` here? There are functions for `ndim` and `shape` but not axes.

2. For a vector like this:

[image: vector example]

we say that we have 2 dimensions in physics/math class because it represents a 2D vector but it looks like `numpy` uses a different notion of this.

Why is it that `ndim` gives `1` and `shape` gives what the dimension is?

```py
>>> c = np.array([1,-3])
>>> c
array([ 1, -3])
>>> c.ndim
1
>>> c.shape
(2,)
```

`np.ndim` gives `1` then?

I have looked at [this tutorial on axes](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-axes-explained/) but haven't been able to get how the axes then apply here.

How would you represent the vector above in Python and `numpy`? Would this be `[1, -3]` in Python or `[[1], [-3]]`? How about in `numpy`? Would it be `np.array([1, -3])` or `np.array([[1], [-3]])`? Which I tend to write, for my eyes' sake, as

```
np.array([
    [1], 
    [-3]
])
```

3. Other than vectors, how would this matrix be represented in both plain Python and `numpy`? The [documentation states](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) that we need to use `np.array`s instead.

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

[image: matrix]

4. When it comes to multidimensional arrays, how would I represent/visualize multiple values for all the points in a 3D cube? Say we have a [Rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube) and each of the sub cubes has a temperature and a color represented with red, green and blue so 4 values for each cube?

Answer (score 0):

A scalar is not an array, so it has 0 dimensions.

`np.array([1,-3])` is a 1D array, so `c.shape` returns a tuple with only one element `(2,)`, just the first dimension and it's telling you there is only 1 dimension and 2 elements in that dimension.

You are correct `np.array([[1], [-3]])` is the vector you have in 2. `c.shape` gives `(2,1)` meaning there are 2 rows and 1 column. `c.ndim` gives `2` since there are 2 dimensions x and y. It's a 2D/planar array

For 3., you would create it as `np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])`. `shape` returns `(3,3)` meaning 3 rows and 3 columns. `ndim` returns 2 because it's still a 2D/planar array.

Answer (score 0):

A `ndarray` has a `shape`, a tuple.  `ndim` is the length of that tuple, and may be 0.  The array has `ndim` axes (sometimes called dimensions).

```
 np.array(5)
```

has shape `()`, 0 `ndim` and no axes.

```
np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

has (4,) shape, and 1 axis.  It can be reshaped to (4,1), or (1,4) or (2,2) or even (2,1,2) or (1,4,1).

Your `A` can be created with

```
A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
```

That's a 9 element 1d array reshaped to (3,3)

`numpy` arrays have a print display, with [] marking dimensional nesting.  `A.tolist()` produces a list with 3 elements, each a 3 element list.

Rows, columns, planes are useful ways of talking about arrays, but are not a formal part of their definition.